# ¿Cómo acceder a vídeos de Youtube sin una autorización oauth 2.0? (Youtube API-PHP)

Tags: php, oauth2, youtube

Guardé en el archivo token.txt los valores necesarios para la autenticación oauth 2.0, mi idea es poder acceder a los videos y listas de reproducción de un usuario en Youtube en particular sin que este tenga que iniciar sesión. Es decir, mostrar los vídeos de mi canal en una página web particular por ejemplo, pero sin yo tener que iniciar sesión.

Mi archivo token.txt es el siguiente (He modificado los valores por seguridad):

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.GlskdfkfmmBaFBB79UJb46pUWxpWkTH5PB2x4kuJ65LJ2q6XmqHeLX3nZiXPIrZ_gvFMu07q_q3gUB2hZitX_XM2jrLPW5JmzDlMZNSxwEOpBmRQiAG5rvd", 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "expires_in": 3600, 
  "refresh_token": "1sdskdmskdsdZ__1GUpr4as"
}
```

Por otro lado, en mi aplicación he incluido el archivo token.txt, considerando la expiración del mismo, de la siguiente manera:

<

```
?php
session_start();
$key = file_get_contents('token.txt');

require_once '\Google\vendor\autoload.php';

$client_id = '379480234592-guh9o2g0learqd2rqo1fl6sjnkjdskdskjdpps.googleusercontent.com'; // Enter your Client ID here
$client_secret = 'OKsdjnsdjsdEvF_As'; // Enter your Client Secret here

$videoPath = "videos/example.mkv";
$videoTitle = "Just an Example Title";
$videoDescription = "This is the YouTube video's description";
$videoCategory = "22";
$videoTags = array("first tag","second tag","third tag");

try{
    // Client init
    $client = new Google_Client();

    /*Agregado para corregir error*/
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array( 'curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
$client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $client->setAccessToken($key);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        /**
         * Check to see if our access token has expired. If so, get a new one and save it to file for future use.
         */
        if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $newToken = $client->getAccessToken();

//            var_dump($newToken["refresh_token"]);

            $client->refreshToken($newToken["refresh_token"]);
            file_put_contents($key, $client->getAccessToken());
        }

        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        // Create a snipet with title, description, tags and category id
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($videoTitle);
        $snippet->setDescription($videoDescription);
        $snippet->setCategoryId($videoCategory);
        $snippet->setTags($videoTags);
        $snippet->setDefaultLanguage("en");
        $snippet->setDefaultAudioLanguage("en");

        $recordingDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails();
        $recordingDetails->setLocationDescription("United States of America");
        $recordingDetails->setRecordingDate("2016-01-20T12:34:00.000Z");
        $locationdetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint();
        $locationdetails->setLatitude("38.8833");
        $locationdetails->setLongitude("77.0167");
        $recordingDetails->setLocation($locationdetails);

        // Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->setPrivacyStatus("public");
        $status->setPublicStatsViewable(false);
        $status->setEmbeddable(false); // Google defect still not editable https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4861

        // Create a YouTube video with snippet and status
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setRecordingDetails($recordingDetails);
        $video->setStatus($status);

        // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
        // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet,recordingDetails", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        /**
         * Video has successfully been uploaded, now lets perform some cleanup functions for this video
         */
        if ($status->status['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded') {
            // Actions to perform for a successful upload
        }

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(true);

    } else{
        // @TODO Log error
        echo 'Problems creating the client';
    }

} catch(Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}

?>
```

El problema es que estoy obteniendo el siguiente error y verdaderamente no se si es alguna configuración de mi aplicación o algo asi, espero de verdad su ayuda:

[image: Al acceder a la URL de mi aplicación aparece este error]

Comment: Puesto que no lo dices en la pregunta, pregunto yo:  ¿Ya creaste tu proyecto en la consola de Google y autorizaste la API de YouTube? Esto viene explicado aquí: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started Por el error que te está dando, parece que no tienes la API autorizada en la consola de Google. Para futuras preguntas, considera a poner el texto del mensaje de error en vez de una imagen, es más fácil ya que las imágenes no se ven, sobre todo en dispositivos móviles.

Comment: Por supuesto que cree mi aplicación anteriormente. Es una buena sugerencia lo de la imagen, no lo habia considerado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He probado lo siguiente y me funciona perfectamente.

Te comento los pasos que he dado:

1. En la [consola de desarrolladores](https://console.developers.google.com) tener el proyecto creado.
2. Dentro de la consola, en la pestaña **Biblioteca** habilitar la **YouTube Data API v3**.
3. Luego, en la pestaña **Credenciales** seleccionar ***Crear credenciales / ID de Cliente de OAuth***.
4. En la siguiente ventana seleccionar **Web**.
5. Le das el nombre que quieras y **muy importante** en la parte que dice ***URIs de redireccionamiento autorizados*** colocas **la misma URL donde se encuentra tu script PHP**, ejemplo: http://www.tusitio.com/tuarchivo.php
6. Pulsas en el botón **Crear** y podrás ver tus credenciales.
7. Colocar tus credenciales del modo siguiente en el código de `tuarchivo.php`:

   a. En la variable `$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID` colocar el valor **ID de cliente** que te muestra la consola, el que termina con `....apps.googleusercontent.com`

   b. En la variable `$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET`colocar el valor **Secreto de cliente** que te muestra la consola.

---

**Código en `tuarchivo.php`**

**Nota 1.** Este código de ejemplo está tomado del [proyecto oficial](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/my_uploads.php), muestra una lista de los vídeos subidos por el usuario. La primera vez que lo ejecutes te pedirá autorización.

**Nota 2.** Es necesario tener los archivos necesarios en tu servidor. La mejor forma de tenerlos es instalándolos mediante composer, ejecutando el siguiente comando, entrando por ssh a la carpeta root de tu sitio web: `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` Si tu hosting no tiene instalado composer tendrás que [copiar manualmente los archivos desde Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

**Nota 3.** En el código, reemplaza las dos líneas donde aparece esto `__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'` por la ruta absoluta, en caso de que quieras instalar los archivos de la API fuera del root o en otra carpeta que no sea el root.

**Nota 4.** Si quieres implementar otra función distinta de la API el procedimiento es casi el mismo, sólo varían las llamadas que hagas a la API para lo que quieras hacer. [En el proyecto oficial hay varios ejemplos de código usando PHP](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/php) y otros lenguajes.

```
<?php

/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
      // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
      // to retrieve that list.
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
          $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```